# How to print value from observavle using async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am trying to print value from my observable class using async pipe, but so far with no luck.
I have following function, that returns observable class from my  API call:

```
private getRecordType() {
   return this.getMyData().pipe(
      tap((res: Data) => {
         return res.recordType;
      }),
   );
}
```

Then I set to `this.recordType` the value that the `getRecordType()` function returns:

```
this.recordType = this.getRecordType();
console.log(this.recordType, 'RECORD_TYPE');
// returns Observable class
```

Then I try to print it in my template:

```
<b>{{ recordType | async }}</b>
```

However this only returns `[object Object]` in my template.
Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tap` doesn't change the emission of an Observable, so your `tap` in this case is doing nothing at all. The operator you're looking for (to modify the emissions of an Observable) is `map`.

Answer (score 1):

The `tap` operator allows you to perform **side-effects** on your observable (see [the documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap)). Returning `res.recordType` into the tap operator won't do what you want

I suggest you to use the [map operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map).